# Assert key in hashmap JUnit

Tags: junit

I thought it was going to be easy but can anyone tell me how I can test HashMap to see if it has some value in JUnit?

```
assertThat(myMap, ??);
```

I tried something like:

```
assertThat(myMap, hasEntry("Key", notNullValue()));
```

...But I couldn't make it compile since my import to hasEntry and notNullValue() is correct.
Does anyone know what the correct import pkg for them should be?

Comment: Why not `assertTrue(myMap.contains("key"));`?

Comment: As an edge case, `myMap.contains("key")` would incorrectly pass with a map that allowed `null` values and contained a `("key", null)` entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.AssertTrue;

assertTrue(myMap.containsKey("yourKey") && myMap.get("yourKey") != null)
```

Comment: As someone finding this page with a similar question, I'm curious why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: @TheGuyWithTheFace Well, I have the same question, and I am not interested in using assertTrue. I am (too) looking for a solution using assertThat() ... what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You're after [`hasEntry(Matcher<? super K> keyMatcher, Matcher<? super V> valueMatcher)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasEntry%28org.hamcrest.Matcher,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29).

The underlying implementation is in [`IsMapContaining`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsMapContaining.html) but,
like most matchers in Hamcrest, it can also be found through [`org.hamcrest.Matchers`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html), in `hamcrest-library`.

Otherwise, your syntax is correct, and `Matchers` also defines `notNullValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

To check the key is in the map:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
...
assertTrue(myMap.containsKey("Key"));
```

Alternatively, to check it has a non-null value:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
...
assertNotNull(myMap.get("Key"));
```

Comment: Be careful with the second approach - it will capture both keys that don't exist and keys that have null values assigned.

Comment: @gronostaj It's not "capturing" anything it shouldn't capture. It is asserting that the key is both present *and* not null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the `assertTrue` approaches, because the feedback is quite limited when the assertion fails.

It can be done with `assertThat` like this:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;


assertThat(myMap, hasEntry(is("Key"), notNullValue()));
```